# Jackson equivalent to XStreamImplicit

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, xstream, swagger

I am having an issue with Jackson and I need to find a way to get the following object to serialize correctly to support swagger docs.

```
public Class Foo{
  @XStreamImplicit
  List<Bar> bars;
}
```

When serialized with XStream this would look something like:

```
<Foo>
  <Bar>b1</Bar>
  <Bar>b2</Bar>
</Foo>
```

What we would like is to have a similar display in JSON but I don't know if this is possible as JSON I believe is essentially a K,V map.

```
{
"bar":"b1",
"bar":"b2"
}
```

Clarification on any of these points would be very helpful!

EDIT:

Looks like the issue lies in swagger, adding the array notation still does not allow the Response Model to be populated for the different response codes.  We believe there is an issue with the annotation not handling collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a map but rather an array. In JSON, you can't have multiple keys with the same name. The JSON equivalent will look like this:

```
{
  "bar": [ "b1", "b2" ]
}
```

Comment: Going back through history, I never selected the correct answer, and this basically describes the root of the problem.  The issue did in fact lie in swaggers handling of the annotation, but was not worth the effort to make changes to the design, so we simply avoided using the swagger functionality we were trying to leverage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class that will show you the JSON output difference between using the arraylist as standard output (as Ron showed) or unwrapping it to flatten the list as an array of objects via @JsonValue

```
public class Answer28482248 {

public static class JsonArrayStandard
{
    ArrayList<String> myList;

    public JsonArrayStandard()
    {
        myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add("a");
        myList.add("b");
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMyList()
    {
        return myList;
    }

}

public static class JsonArrayAsValue extends JsonArrayStandard
{
    public JsonArrayAsValue()
    {
        super();
    }

    @JsonValue
    public ArrayList<String> getMyList()
    {
        return myList;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        JsonArrayStandard standard = new JsonArrayStandard();
        JsonArrayStandard asValue = new JsonArrayAsValue();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(standard));
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(asValue));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

}

The output is:

{"myList":["a","b"]}

["a","b"]